# SQL Calculate Consecutive hours

Tags: sql, aggregate, recursive-query, sql-server-2017, gaps-and-islands

Need to calculate consecutive hours.

Here is the data

```
╔════╦══════════╦════════════╦═══════════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║ ClientID ║ Date       ║ From(Min) ║ To    ║  
╠════╬══════════╬════════════╬═══════════╬═══════╣
║ 101║ 2563     ║ 2020-06-19 ║ 360       ║ 1080  ║  
║ 102║ 2563     ║ 2020-06-19 ║ 1080      ║ 1140  ║ 
║ 103║ 2563     ║ 2020-06-19 ║ 1140      ║ 1200  ║  
║ 104║ 2561     ║ 2020-06-19 ║ 360       ║ 1080  ║  
║ 105║ 2563     ║ 2020-06-19 ║ 1200      ║ 1440  ║  
║ 106║ 2563     ║ 2020-06-20 ║ 0         ║ 60    ║  
║ 107║ 2561     ║ 2020-05-19 ║ 1080      ║ 1140  ║ 
║ 107║ 2563     ║ 2020-05-20 ║ 1080      ║ 1140  ║ 
╚════╩══════════╩════════════╩═══════════╩═══════╝
```

This the client has a limit of the amount of consecutive hours allowed.

Here is the result I'm looking for

```
╔══════════╦════════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═══════╦═══════════════════╗
║ ClientID ║ Date       ║ From    ║ To      ║ Hours ║ Consecutive Hours ║
╠══════════╬════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════╣═══════════════════╣
║ 2563     ║ 2020-06-19 ║ 6:00am  ║ 6:00pm  ║ 12    ║ 12                ║
║ 2563     ║ 2020-06-19 ║ 6:00pm  ║ 7:00pm  ║ 1     ║ 13                ║
║ 2563     ║ 2020-06-19 ║ 7:00pm  ║ 8:00pm  ║ 1     ║ 14                ║
║ 2563     ║ 2020-06-19 ║ 8:00pm  ║ 12:00am ║ 4     ║ 18                ║
║ 2563     ║ 2020-06-20 ║ 12:00am ║ 1:00am  ║ 1     ║ 19                ║
║ 2563     ║ 2020-06-20 ║ 6:00pm  ║ 7:00pm  ║ 1     ║ 1                 ║
║ 2561     ║ 2020-06-19 ║ 6:00am  ║ 6:00pm  ║ 12    ║ 12                ║
║ 2561     ║ 2020-06-19 ║ 7:00pm  ║ 8:00pm  ║ 1     ║ 13                ║
╚══════════╩════════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═══════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Or a formula to calculate if client exceeds the allowed consecutive hours.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: that was quick @DaleK, will post what I have tomorrow (from work). Thank You

Comment: What is the maximum number of allowed consecutive hours?

Comment: Please verify if you have any typos in the sample data.  The source data has dates in 2018, but result only in 2020. Also, what version of SQL Sever do you use? Please tag with the version.

Comment: @monsey11, Overall, this looks like a [Packing Intervals](http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/packing-intervals/) problem that Itzik Ben-Gan discussed in great detail in his article. He also shows there how to ignore gaps of up to a certain length.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Allowed consecutive hours varies.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov you are right about the typos. SQL Server 2017 version 14.0.2027.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  Because you are dealing with minutes, it makes more sense to me to accumulate minutes rather than hours.  You can divide by 60 to get hours:

```
select t.*,
       sum(tom - fromm) over (partition by clientid, date, grp order by fromm) as consecutive_minutes
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_tom = fromm then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by clientid, date order by fromm) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   dateadd(minute, fromm, date) as fromdt,
                   dateadd(minute, tom, date) as todt,
                   lag(tom) over (partition by clientid, date order by fromm) as prev_tom
            from t
          ) t
     ) t
order by clientid, date, fromm;
```

EDIT:

To handle counting hours across days is really just tweaking the above query:

```
select t.*,
       sum(tom - fromm) over (partition by clientid, grp order by date, fromm) as consecutive_minutes
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_todt = fromdt then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by clientid order by date, fromm) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   dateadd(minute, fromm, date) as fromdt,
                   dateadd(minute, tom, date) as todt,
                   lag(dateadd(minute, tom, date)) over (partition by clientid order by date, fromm) as prev_todt
            from t
          ) t
     ) t
order by clientid, date, fromm;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8b141948106f829256bfef413b6d4e20) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: It only calculates within the same date. If hours overlap more than one day.

Comment: If hours overlap more than one day it does not add it to the consecutive_minutes. Date: 7/7/20 tom: 1440 really means 7/8/20 12am

Comment: The date field is a Date datatype not DateTime. needed to cast to datetime for the DATEADD function.

Comment: @monsey11 . . . The same basic query works with some tweaks.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank You. Will set as answer. Wondering if there is better option for performance. The user gets prompted as he enters the dates and times. Also need to ability to check large datasets.  this is just part of many other validations it checks, so speed is particularly important.

Comment: @monsey11 . . . This should have pretty reasonable performance.  It is only using window functions.

Comment: Thank You @GordonLinoff. Is it easy to modify this statement to calculate consecutive days?

Comment: @monsey11 . . . If you can't divide by (24*60), then I would suggest asking a new question.